# How to do AffinityKey join using key as multiple column of two caches/tables?

Tags: ignite

I am planning to join two caches having multiple columns as key. But I am finding difficulty to write join query. 
Here is the full code. Please help to write join query using two caches/tables

person value object:

```
private static class Person implements Serializable {
        private PersonKey personKey;
        private OrgKey orgKey;
        @QuerySqlField
        private String firstName;
        @QuerySqlField
        private String lastName;
        @QueryTextField
        private String resume;
        /** Salary (indexed). */
        @QuerySqlField(index = true)
        private double salary;
        /**
         * Custom cache key to guarantee that person is always collocated with
         * its organization.
         */
        private transient AffinityKey<PersonKey> key;


        Person(Organization org, PersonKey key, String firstName, String lastName, double salary, String resume) {
            // Generate unique ID for this person.
            this.personKey = key;
            this.orgKey = org.key;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.resume = resume;
            this.salary = salary;
        }
```

person key object:

```
private static class PersonKey implements Serializable {

        @QuerySqlField(index = true)
        private UUID id;
        @QuerySqlField(index = true)
        private String location;

        public PersonKey(UUID id, String location) {
            this.id = id;
            this.location = location;
        }
    }
```

Organization value object:

```
private static class Organization implements Serializable {
        /** Organization ID (indexed). */
        private OrgKey key;
        /** Organization name (indexed). */
        @QuerySqlField(index = true)
        private String name;

        public Organization(OrgKey key, String name) {
            this.key = key;
            this.name = name;
        }
```

organization key class:

```
private static class OrgKey implements Serializable {

    @QuerySqlField(index = true)
    private int id;
    @QuerySqlField(index = true)
    private String location;
    private UUID orgId;

    public OrgKey(int id, String location, UUID orgId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.location = location;
        this.orgId = orgId;
    }
}
```

Join query:

```
IgniteCache<AffinityKey<PersonKey>, Person> cache = Ignition.ignite().cache(PERSON_CACHE);

        String sql = "select * " + "from Persons, Organizations as org " + "where Persons.id = org.orgId";

        QueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery(sql));
```

Ignite cache creation:

```
/** Organizations cache name. */
    private static final String ORG_CACHE = "Organizations";
    /** Persons cache name. */
    private static final String PERSON_CACHE = "Persons";

    CacheConfiguration<OrgKey, Organization> orgCacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<>(ORG_CACHE);
                orgCacheCfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED); // Default.
                orgCacheCfg.setIndexedTypes(OrgKey.class, Organization.class);

                CacheConfiguration<AffinityKey<PersonKey>, Person> personCacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<>(PERSON_CACHE);
                personCacheCfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED); // Default.
                personCacheCfg.setIndexedTypes(AffinityKey.class, Person.class);
```

Comment: How are you "unable to write join query"? What does that mean to you?

Comment: there are examples for join with key as single column but in my case, i have two column as key, tried all possible ways but not able to write join query of two caches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this simple example, I do join by two fields in keys:

```
package sql;

import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.ignite.Ignite;
import org.apache.ignite.IgniteCache;
import org.apache.ignite.Ignition;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.CacheAtomicityMode;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.query.FieldsQueryCursor;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.query.SqlFieldsQuery;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.query.annotations.QuerySqlField;
import org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration;
import org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration;
import org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi;
import org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class DoubleJoin {
    public static final String DEFAULT_CACHE_NAME = "DEFAULT";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        IgniteConfiguration ignCfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

        TcpDiscoverySpi spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
        TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder finder = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();
        finder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1"));
        spi.setIpFinder(finder);

        ignCfg.setDiscoverySpi(spi);

        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(ignCfg);

        CacheConfiguration cacheCfg = getCacheConfiguration();

        final IgniteCache cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheCfg);

        cache.put(new A(1, 2), new AVal(100));
        cache.put(new B(1, 2), new BVal(100));

        FieldsQueryCursor cursor = cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("SELECT * " +
            "FROM AVal " +
            "INNER JOIN BVal ON AVal.a1=BVal.b1 AND AVal.a2=BVal.b2;"));

        for (Object o : cursor) {
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    }

    static class A {
        @AffinityKeyMapped
        @QuerySqlField
        int a1;
        @QuerySqlField
        int a2;

        public A(int a1, int a2) {
            this.a1 = a1;
            this.a2 = a2;
        }
    }

    static class AVal {
        @QuerySqlField
        int aV;

        public AVal(int aV) {
            this.aV = aV;
        }
    }

    static class B {
        @AffinityKeyMapped
        @QuerySqlField
        int b1;
        @QuerySqlField
        int b2;

        public B(int b1, int b2) {
            this.b1 = b1;
            this.b2 = b2;
        }
    }

    static class BVal {
        @QuerySqlField
        int bV;

        public BVal(int bV) {
            this.bV = bV;
        }
    }

    @NotNull private static CacheConfiguration<Integer, Integer> getCacheConfiguration() {
        CacheConfiguration<Integer, Integer> cfg = new CacheConfiguration<>();

        cfg.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
        cfg.setName(DEFAULT_CACHE_NAME);

        cfg.setIndexedTypes(A.class, AVal.class, B.class, BVal.class);

        return cfg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the example is good, but please let me know how to use Affinity key so that both table keys will be on the same node.

Comment: One more doubt in the example you are using only one cache with two keys and two values, is two keys of same values are saved in the same node without making it as ' AffinityKeyMapped' ??

Comment: I updated the example above, I added @AffinityKeyMapped annotation, only one field can have this annotation. This annotation means that ignite will use this field to calculate partition for this record. In the example it's A.a1 and B.b1, so records with A.a1 == B.b1 will be located in the same partition and hence on the same node: apacheignite.readme.io/docs/… – Michael 21 secs ago   edit

Answer (score 0):

I did a small modification to CLASS A, please correct me if I am wrong. I have used affinity key mapper as per the below link.
https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation

```
 package com.cache;

import java.util.Arrays;

import org.apache.ignite.Ignite;
import org.apache.ignite.IgniteCache;
import org.apache.ignite.Ignition;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.CacheAtomicityMode;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.affinity.AffinityKeyMapped;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.query.FieldsQueryCursor;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.query.SqlFieldsQuery;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.query.annotations.QuerySqlField;
import org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration;
import org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration;
import org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi;
import org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class DoubleJoin {
    public static final String DEFAULT_CACHE_NAME = "DEFAULT";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        IgniteConfiguration ignCfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

        TcpDiscoverySpi spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
        TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder finder = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();
        finder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1"));
        spi.setIpFinder(finder);

        ignCfg.setDiscoverySpi(spi);

        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(ignCfg);

        CacheConfiguration cacheCfg = getCacheConfiguration();

        final IgniteCache cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cacheCfg);

        cache.put(new A(1, 2), new AVal(100, new A(1, 2)));
        cache.put(new A(2, 3), new AVal(200, new A(2, 3)));
        cache.put(new A(3, 4), new AVal(300, new A(3, 4)));
        cache.put(new B(1, 2), new BVal(200));

        FieldsQueryCursor cursor = cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery("SELECT BVall.b1, BVall.b2, BVall.bV " + "FROM AVal "
                + "INNER JOIN (select *  from BVal where BVal.bV = ?) BVall ON AVal.a1=BVall.b1 AND AVal.a2=BVall.b2  ;").setArgs(200));

        for (Object o : cursor) {
            System.out.println(o);
        }
    }

    static class A {
        @QuerySqlField
        int a1;
        @QuerySqlField
        int a2;
        @AffinityKeyMapped
        int b1;
        @AffinityKeyMapped
        int b2;

        public A(int a1, int a2) {
            this.a1 = a1;
            this.a2 = a2;
            this.b1 = a1;
            this.b2 = a2;
        }
    }

    static class AVal {
        @QuerySqlField
        int aV;

        A a;

        public AVal(int aV,  A a) {
            this.aV = aV;
            this.a = a;
        }
    }

    static class B {
        @QuerySqlField
        int b1;
        @QuerySqlField
        int b2;

        public B(int b1, int b2) {
            this.b1 = b1;
            this.b2 = b2;
        }
    }

    static class BVal {
        @QuerySqlField
        int bV;

        public BVal(int bV) {
            this.bV = bV;
        }
    }

    @NotNull
    private static CacheConfiguration<Integer, Integer> getCacheConfiguration() {
        CacheConfiguration<Integer, Integer> cfg = new CacheConfiguration<>();

        cfg.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
        cfg.setName(DEFAULT_CACHE_NAME);

        cfg.setIndexedTypes(A.class, AVal.class, B.class, BVal.class);

        return cfg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see my updated example, also I added a comment with some explanation about how @AffinityKeyMapped annotation works.